# Remove illegal characters from XML

Tags: php, xml

How can I remove the extra quotation marks from the returned XML string?

```
<Item Type="BO" Chan="12" " Inhibit="NO" " Manual="OFF" />
```

Normally I would be able to get data "BO", "12", "NO", "OFF", but the extra quotation marks interfere with this process.

Is there anyway I can remove the characters, yet still obtain the data?

Comment: Better yet, is there any way you can avoid getting invalid XML in the first place? Where does it come from?

Comment: (But if you *definitely, absolutely, 100% cannot have the source corrected*, you can try something like this: http://regex101.com/r/jH9gL7/1).

Comment: Hi @Marty, I cannot change the received XML string. It is coming from a device.

Comment: @user3883066 is this only a sample? is the real xml is big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case of malformed XML sounds like a good job for the [Tidy XML repair parser](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php):

```
$malformed_xml = '<Item Type="BO" Chan="12" " Inhibit="NO" " Manual="OFF" />';

$repaired_xml = tidy_repair_string($malformed_xml, ['input-xml' => 1]);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($repaired_xml);

foreach ($xml->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", $key, $value);
}
```

Output:

```
Type: BO
Chan: 12
Inhibit: NO
Manual: OFF
```

Comment: Came back to this a year later. Thank you very much!